# QSqlQuery is only returning two columns with SELECT * FROM ..., any idea why I don't get all the columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, qt, qtsql

I have a table with 16 columns. I perform a `SELECT` using the `QSqlQuery` class. I get two rows as expected, but only the first 2 columns out of the 16.

Here is a simplified version of the query

```
QSqlQuery query(f_db);
query.prepare(QString("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status = 'good'");
query.exec();
query.next();
int const max(query.size());  // here max == 2 instead of 16
for(int idx(0); idx < max; ++idx)
{
    QVariant v(it->second->value(idx));
    ...v is correct for column 1 and 2...
}
```

Any idea why MySQL would not return all 16 columns.

Comment: Try listing a column that is not returned instead of `*`. What happens?

Comment: what if you did select them by their columns, does it the same data?

Comment: query.size() is no. of rows and not no. of columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending to this [article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html) you are getting number of rows not number of columns, `query.size()` returning the number of records. however `query.record().count` returning the number of columns